# How to Handle Image Sequences in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I currently have a basic 1 page React Native app for iOS (iPad 4) which shows the camera feed and overlays an image sequence. This image sequence consists of 149 frames and it loops continually.

I achieve the image sequence loop by replacing the source of the `Image` component 24 times per second.

Here is the app class (without the style props).

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            frame: 1
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let frame = this.state.frame;

            frame++;

            if (frame > 149) {
                frame = 1;
            }

            this.setState({frame});
        }, 1000 / 24);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Camera ref={(cam) => {this.camera = cam}}>
                    <Text>Frame: {this.state.frame}</Text>
                    <Image source={{uri: `./gifs/${this.state.frame}.gif`}}/>
                </Camera>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Which gives this as the output.

[image: Image of the app.]

The problem I am getting is that the app crashes after varying time lengths. Sometimes it can run for 3 seconds before crashing and sometimes it can run for 2 minutes before crashing.

I'm guessing this is a memory issue, but in the debugger in Xcode it was only using ~10% of the available memory. Is there a way to somehow only load the images I need into memory and remove the images I don't or is this managed automatically?

Comment: hi there. I was wondering if the stream of images is saved to gifs automatically, or are you doing somehow doing that behind the scenes? Because I am trying to access the raw came stream data and am unable to unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [react-native-sprite](https://github.com/williamngan/react-native-sprite), which animates an image sequence using native `UIImageView` instead of a javascript setInterval solution.